# How do I install Ububtu linux on Windows 7 machine (no CD drive), not saving Windows OK?

Tags: system-installation

I want to convert my old 32 bit HP netbook with no CD drive to Umbuntu linux. I am a newby but worked in UNIX 28 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

[You can install from USB.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

The general procedure to install Ubuntu (or Ubuntu flavour, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) from a USB flash drive is:

```
Acquire the correct Ubuntu installation files ('the ISO')
Put Ubuntu onto your USB flash drive
Configure your computer to boot from USB flash drive and boot from it

Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it
Install Ubuntu to your internal drive (hard disk drive or solid state drive).
```